# The correct way to say Measure units or Units of measure

Tags: grammar

which one is correct and why, or are they both correct:

1. measure units
2. units of measure?

when i start to google it, I saw only 1st variant.

Comment: This type of question is better suited to our sister site, for people who are learning English - http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Max Williams: I don't think this is really a matter of learning English, *units of measurement*, *units of measure*, *measure units* and *measurement units* are all four used without a huge visible distinction between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer "Units of measure".
But you can say "Measuring units" over "Measure units".
Depends on you, both are correct.